# Can't upgrade my videocard drivers? Ubuntu 14.04 Radeon Pro WX 3100

Tags: 14.04, drivers, radeon

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I have a new graphics card: [AMD Radeon Pro WX 3100](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/professional-graphics/radeon-pro/radeon-pro-wx-x100-series/radeon-pro-wx-3100)

On the AMD drivers website, the drivers only show downloads for Ubuntu 16.

I've tried installing the Ubuntu 16 AMD drivers, but it stops itself saying this isn't (14) the correct version of Ubuntu.

I've looked on the Additional Drivers tab, nothing appears there either.

I've tried a lot of the solutions in other questions, and google searches, but there is a lot of old, outdated information (and confusing!) out there.

My monitor can handle 2560 x 1695 resolution but that is not an option on the screen below:

[image: display]

Also when my display goes to sleep, there seems no way to get it to come back on? (assuming old drivers problem).

This is what I have:

[image: graphics card]

Kernal version: `Linux 4.4.0-148-generic`

I'm hoping someone can help please, and give me an answer that is not, "upgrade your ubuntu version." :-)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sign up for Ubuntu Advantage, it allows you your EOL release to become Ubuntu 14.04 ESM which still receives support.  ESM like releases are off-topic here though  (*and it's not a upgrade-your Ubuntu release answer!*)

Comment: thanks I'll take a look :-) I thought Ubuntu 14.04 was LTS not EOL though?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was a LONG-TERM-Support release with 5 years of support starting 2014-April (thus 14.04) ending April 25, 2019 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/) - it's now EOL or end-of-life & thus off-topic here.  It can be changed to Ubuntu 14.04 ESM with Ubuntu Advantage (link can be found in fridge post) but ESM releases are still off-topic here and support requires payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS reached EOL on 25 April 2019.

> I'm hoping someone can help please, and give me an answer that is not,
>   "upgrade your ubuntu version."

EOL releases are unsupported and thus off-topic here, and given you don't want to upgrade to a later release - the only on-topic answer left is

https://ubuntu.com/esm

> Extended Security Maintenance Security updates for 14.04 LTS until
>   2022

A link can be found in the EOL notice for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/)

Comment: thanks! I didn't realise about the EOL ... thats food for thought :+1:

Comment: 14.04 means the 2014-April release of Ubuntu (ie. *yy.mm* format is used for releases) making it pretty easy to work out. 14.04 + 5 years = 19.04 (2019.April) EOL

Comment: ah nice! TIL :-)

Comment: For anyone reading this and wanting an answer: I sucked it up and moved to a still supported LTS version aka 18.04 (and the graphics are now crisp as hell :) )